# How to execute a exe file using fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse

I want   to call an exe file in my fitnesse test case.

Help me in calling an exe  file in my test cases

Comment: fitnesse is a testing framework.  http://www.fitnesse.org

Comment: http://www.fitnesse.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With fitnesse, you'll need to write a fixture to run the EXE (and/or find a fitnesse plugin to do it for you).  The easiest way is to write a simple fixture and just run

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<cmd>);
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Steven Mastandrea's answer is right but it does require you to write you a Java class extending one of the provided fixture's from Fitnesse and compile and put the class files in Fitnesse classpath and then use it.

There is a much simpler way of doing it if you use [Generic Fixture](http://anubhava.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/introducing-generic-fixture-for-fitnesse/) like this:

```
!| Generic Fixture |
| exec | mycommand.exe | | expected outpout |
```

**Disclaimer:** [Generic Fixture](http://anubhava.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/introducing-generic-fixture-for-fitnesse/) was written and distributed by me as open source 2 years ago on sourceforge.

Comment: using this it executes the file in browser window i want that exe file should open seperately

Comment: The way the Fitnesse works is that it creates a new Java process and executes your test case. Generic Fixture then takes over then and executes your `.exe` file using `getRuntime().exec()` method and then it displays the output of your .exe in the browser. Or if you want you can supply expected output and it will mark the test pass/fail after comparing actual and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

With fitSharp on Windows, you can write this:

|with|type|System.Diagnostics.Process|

|with|start|C:\dev\myFileImporter.exe||-f c:\dev\data\file.txt|

|wait for exit|

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking the [CommandLineFixture](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?CommandLineFixture) as a baseline, and expand it from there. The CommandLineFixture has a lot of functionality and is well commented and easily extended should you wish to do so.

This fixture incorporates Steven's code, but has a lot more functionality than simply `exec`, including being able to asynchronously spawn processes, search output for expected results, etc.

Post a command if you feel some examples of how to use it would be helpful!